# Index out of Range with my values

Tags: c#

I am attempting to print off the times 'NONE appears, as I have all my other information printing off accurate. I believe it may be something I am doing with my values but every time i  fix something and get my code to compile, I keep getting zero's as my answer. Why is this?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;

namespace ConsoleApplication33
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        FileStream fStream = new FileStream("Students.txt", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
        StreamReader inFile = new StreamReader(fStream);
        string inValue;
        string[] values;
        double GPA;
        double total = 0;
        double counter = 0;
        double count = 0;
        double counti = 0;
        List<string> Anderson = new List<string>(); //Anderson
        List<string> gpa = new List<string>(); //GPA
        List<string> noemail = new List<string>(); // email

        while (!inFile.EndOfStream)
        {
            inValue = inFile.ReadLine();
            values = inValue.Split(" ".ToCharArray());
            if (inValue.StartsWith("(LIST (LIST "))
            {
                values = inValue.Split(" ".ToCharArray());
                GPA = double.Parse(values[8]);
                total = total + GPA;
                counter++;
            }
            if (values[2] == "'Anderson")
            {
                Anderson.Add(values[2]);
                count++;
            }
            if (values[2] == " ")
            {
                counter++;
            }
            if (values[6] == "'NONE")
            {
                noemail.Add(values[6]);
                counti++;
            }

        }
        double average = (double)total / (double)counter;
        Console.WriteLine("The average gpa is..." + average.ToString());
        Console.WriteLine("Total last names with Anderson is..." + count.ToString());
        Console.WriteLine("Total number of students is..." + counter.ToString());
        Console.WriteLine("Total is..." + counti.ToString());
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Did you come up with the format of the text file yourself? You're better off using either JSON or XML serialization for formatting, this would also make deserialization much easier with less code.

Comment: @JunWeiLee No, unfortunately I did not make this format

Comment: You are searching for 'NONE', but in reality your file has 'NONE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are off by one when trying to figure out whether an email is present or not

```
FileStream fStream = new FileStream("Students.txt", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
StreamReader inFile = new StreamReader(fStream);
string inValue;
string[] values;
double GPA;
double total = 0;
double counter = 0;
double count = 0;
double counti = 0;
double countNoTelephone = 0;
List<string> Anderson = new List<string>(); //Anderson
List<string> gpa = new List<string>(); //GPA
List<string> noemail = new List<string>(); // email

while (!inFile.EndOfStream)
{
    inValue = inFile.ReadLine();

    if (inValue.StartsWith("(LIST (LIST "))
    {
        values = inValue.Split(" ".ToCharArray());
        GPA = double.Parse(values[8]);
        total = total + GPA;
        counter++;

        if (values[2] == "'Anderson")
        {
            Anderson.Add(values[2]);
            count++;
        }
        if (values[2] == " ")
        {
            counter++;
        }
        if (values[7] == "'NONE") // you got this off by one
        {
            noemail.Add(values[6]);
            counti++;
        }

        if (values[6] == "'NONE") // you are not counting this
        {
            countNoTelephone++;
        }
    }
}
double average = total / counter;
Console.WriteLine("The average gpa is..." + average);
Console.WriteLine("Total last names with Anderson is..." + count);
Console.WriteLine("Total number of students is..." + counter);
Console.WriteLine("Total with no emails is..." + counti);
Console.WriteLine("Total with no telephone is..." + countNoTelephone);
Console.WriteLine("Total with no telephone or emails are..." + (countNoTelephone + counti)); // add both no telephone and no emails together
Console.ReadKey();
```

A better way to do this is to serialize your text file into .NET objects, and then perform calculations on them. Have a look at this

```
public class Student
{
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string Code { get; set; } // not sure what the J M T K code is
    public string Telephone { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public double Gpa { get; set; }
}

private static void Main(string[] args)
{
FileStream fStream = new FileStream("Students.txt", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
StreamReader inFile = new StreamReader(fStream);
string inValue;
string[] values;

List<Student> students = new List<Student>();

while (!inFile.EndOfStream)
{
    inValue = inFile.ReadLine();

    if (inValue.StartsWith("(LIST (LIST "))
    {
        values = inValue.Split(" ".ToCharArray());

        Student student = new Student();

        student.LastName = values[2];
        student.FirstName = values[3];
        student.Code = values[4];
        student.Telephone = values[6];
        student.Email = values[7];
        student.Gpa = Convert.ToDouble(values[8]);

        students.Add(student);
    }
}
var noTelephone = students.Count(x => x.Telephone == "'NONE");
int noEmails = students.Count(x => x.Email == "'NONE");

Console.WriteLine("The average gpa is..." + students.Average(x => x.Gpa));
Console.WriteLine("Total last names with Anderson is..." + students.Count(x => x.LastName == "'Anderson"));
Console.WriteLine("Total number of students is..." + students.Count);
Console.WriteLine("Total with no emails is..." + noEmails);
Console.WriteLine("Total with no telephone is..." + noTelephone);
Console.WriteLine("Total with no telephone or emails are..." + (noEmails + noTelephone));
Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

You can easily perform other operations on the data afterwards and you have a nice object to work with, instead of guessing what values[7] is.

Comment: Well it says 'NONE for some phone numbers and 'NONE for some email addresses and I am trying to sift the data where it identifies the differences between whats an email and phone being none

Comment: That counts every actual NONE in the entire text field, is what I am trying to say, instead of differentiating it

Comment: You'll need to update your question to explain what each field means, it's quite a challenge to decipher it. For example, what's (LIST (LIST and why do some rows start with it? There's no sample data that starts with that

Comment: I have updated my answer to fix your bug, as well as a better way to do things

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you're after but if you want to count the number of times 'NONE' occurs in the file, this should work:

```
while (!inFile.EndOfStream)
    {
        inValue = inFile.ReadLine()
        myCount = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Matches(inValue, "NONE").Count;

     }
    Console.WriteLine("NONE occurs {0} time(s).", myCount);
```

Answer (score 0):

When you split the first line of your input file by `" "`:

`students (LIST`

You only get 2 delimited values, causing the Index out of Range exception when you try to access more values, e.g.

`if (values[2] == "'Anderson")`

You will have to check the number of available delimited values before you try to access them.

Comment: Why does if (values[2] == "'Anderson') work, as it shows the correct answer, but NONE does not?

Comment: I tested with you updated input (removing 1st line), and it output `Total is...1`. Is this what you're  expecting?

Comment: you are using my original code and just deleting that first line in the text file? I am still somehow getting the error message

Comment: I am. What's the error message? If it's still Index out of Range, did you use the debugger to check how many strings are present in `values`?

Comment: {"Index was outside the bounds of the array."} It is, I am checking it right now trying to figure it out

Comment: After removing that first line in the text file any amount in my value that is higher than 0 is out of bounds, but when at 0 it gives me 0 as an answer.

Comment: OK, I think you've included the empty lines in your input. That's why after you split it you're still getting one value. Anyway, you should add some boundary check before you access values[n].